# Styling text within a button

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I would like to have a multi line string of text in my button, like this:

```
myButton.Text = "abc" + Environment.NewLine + "123";
```

Is it possible to style each line separately ? e.g. I would like the first line to be bold and the second line italicized ?

If this is not possible, can someone recommend an alternative way of achieving this ?

Thanks

Comment: You can't do it with the stock button.  But inherit your own class from Button and override the drawing and you can.

Comment: Thanks - I have no idea where to start doing this, could you point me to a resource or provide a very basic example ? Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be a lot of work to do this right, but here's a start.

This would be the inherited class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class MyButton : Button
    {
        private Boolean _pressed = false;

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            if (_pressed)
                ControlPaint.DrawButton(pevent.Graphics, pevent.ClipRectangle, ButtonState.Pushed);
            else
                ControlPaint.DrawButton(pevent.Graphics, pevent.ClipRectangle, ButtonState.Normal);

            pevent.Graphics.DrawString("Line 1", new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.5f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular), System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.PointF(2.0f, 2.0f));
            pevent.Graphics.DrawString("Line 2", new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 14.0f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), System.Drawing.Brushes.Red, new System.Drawing.PointF(2.0f, 17.0f));
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
        {
            _pressed = false;
            base.OnMouseUp(mevent);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs mevent)
        {
            _pressed = true;
            base.OnMouseDown(mevent);
        }
    }
}
```

You would have to either programmatically add a `MyButton` object to your form, or add a normal button and go into `Form1.Designer.cs` and change it's type from `Button` to `MyButton`.

Notice that instead of using `Text1 + Environment.NewLine + Text2`, I'm instead drawing by precise positioning.  That allows you to calculate exactly where it needs to be.

You can further help yourself by leveraging [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx).  That can help you determine the exact size of the string you draw to know how much room it consumes.

You'll also need to ensure that the button is always large enough to properly display the text you mean to show.  Also can be done in the override, or just make it a set size at design time and make the text fit to it.  Whichever.